# TreeView in FXML

Tags: javafx, treeview, fxml

How can I create a TreeView in FXML including all the branches and components in it? I can't find documentation about it. There is just code about how to populate it but I want to do it in FXML so y can have the design apart of the logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no specific documentation for FXML (beyond the [Introduction to FXML document](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.fxml/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html)): but there is no need for any. An element beginning with an uppercase character is an instruction to instantiate the class of that name, so

```xml
<TreeView></TreeView>
```

will instantiate a `TreeView`. Attributes correspond to properties, so if you needed you could do

```xml
<TreeView editable="true"></TreeView>
```

Nested elements beginning with lower case also correspond to properties, and will be set to the enclosed FXML structure. So you can create a tree view with code like

```xml
<TreeView fx:id = "treeView">
    <root>
        <TreeItem fx:id="rootItem" value="Root" expanded="true">
            <children>
                <TreeItem fx:id="child1" value="Child 1" expanded="true">
                    <children>
                        <TreeItem fx:id="child11" value="Child 1.1"></TreeItem>
                        <TreeItem fx:id="child12" value="Child 1.2"></TreeItem>
                    </children>
                </TreeItem>
                <TreeItem fx:id="child2" value="Child 2">
                    <children>
                        <TreeItem fx:id="child21" value="Child 2.1"></TreeItem>
                        <TreeItem fx:id="child22" value="Child 2.2"></TreeItem>
                    </children>
                </TreeItem>
            </children>
        </TreeItem>
    </root>
</TreeView>
```

You can, of course, see all the properties in the [API documentation](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/package-summary.html).

Comment: Are the `fx:id's` for the second `TreeItem` a typo?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it's even usefull for any other JavaFX component.